# Changing `self` for another instance of same object?

Tags: python, design-patterns, singleton, factory-pattern

I want to create a class, and all objects need to have a unique identifier `key`, and If I attempt to create a new instance of the object with a previously existent key, the instance should be the same as the one that already existing.

Similar to a singleton class, but in this case instead of one class, there are many but different.

My first approach was this

```
class Master:
    existent = {}
    def __init__(self, key, value=None):
        try:
            self = Master.existent[key]
            return 
        except KeyError:
            Master.existent[key] = self
        # Rest of the __init__ method
```

But when I compare two objects, something like this `A = Master('A', 0)` and `B = Master('B', 0)`, the `B` doesn't share any attributes that It should have, and if the Master class has any `_method` (single underscore), It also doesn't appear.

Any Idea how could I do this?

I think this is similar to the Factory Methods Pattern, but I'm still having trouble to find the parallels, or how to implemented in an elegant form.

EDIT:

The class basically has two proprieties and that's it, but many things would Inherit and/or contain instances of this as type, the *easy* way I thought I could do it, was extracting the properties from the existing instance corresponding to said `key`, assigning them to the new instance and abuse from the fact that they will have same `hash` output and the the `equal` operator will behave according to hashes so I can use `==` and `is` operators with no problem.

This Idea solves my problem, but overall I think this could be a common or interesting enough scenario to tackle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the answer from `A Kruger`, I have another solution building off the use of the `__new__` method as suggested. The main difference in this answer is that there is no need to create an inner `__Master` class. The `__new__` method is automatically called when `Master()` is invoked, and is expected to return an instance of the `Master` class. In my answer, the `__new__` method returns a new instance, if needed, but returns an instance from the `existent` dictionary, if possible. Note that the user accesses the `Master` class as usual, i.e., they just call `Master('A', 0)`. This is made possible by making the `Master` class extend `object`.

Here is the code:

```
class Master(object):
    existent = {}

    def __init__(self, key, value=None):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        if not key in Master.existent:
            Master.existent[key] = self

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        key = args[0]
        if key in Master.existent:
            return Master.existent[key]
        else:
            return super(Master, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __str__(self):
        return('id: ' + str(id(self)) + ', key=' + str(self.key) + ', value=' + str(self.value))

A = Master('A', 0)
print('A = ' + str(A))
B = Master('A', 1)
print('\nAfter B created:')
print('B = ' + str(B))
print('A = ' + str(A))
B.value = 99
print('\nAfter B modified:')
print('B = ' + str(B))
print('A = ' + str(A))
C = Master('C', 3)
print('\nC = ' + str(C))
```

And here is the output:

```
A = id: 140023450750200, key=A, value=0

After B created:
B = id: 140023450750200, key=A, value=1
A = id: 140023450750200, key=A, value=1

After B modified:
B = id: 140023450750200, key=A, value=99
A = id: 140023450750200, key=A, value=99

C = id: 140023450750256, key=C, value=3
```

Note that `A` and `B` have the same `id` (they are the same object). Also note that changes to `A` or `B` affect each other, since they are the same object.

Comment: Agreed -- I realized this as well and made the change to mine just before you posted this.  Using the `_Master` subclass was derived from [examples for singletons](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Singleton.html)

Comment: After a while reading the Python Documentation and doing some tests, turns out the problem is that I didn't knew how `__new__` actually works, your solution works perfectly as I need. 
I still need to resolve my _issues_ with this method. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that using the `__init__()` method, because a new instance of the class has already been created when that method is called. You probably need to create a factory type method something like:

```
class Master:
    existent = {}
    init_OK = False

    def __init__(self, key, value=None):
        if not Master.init_OK:
            raise Exception('Direct call to Master() is not allowed')
        Master.init_OK = False
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        Master.existent[key] = self

    @staticmethod
    def make(key, value=None):
        try:
            inst = Master.existent[key]
        except:
            Master.init_OK = True
            inst = Master(key, value=value)
        return inst
```

Comment: I would really like that the user doesn't bother using the factory method, and that he can instantiate the object as if it where a regular python object, the factory method It's explicit for the programmer but, not that clear the user of the module if you consider they could be not as familiar with this design pattern thingy or OO in genera, the Idea is that the user of the module, is at a basic python level. 
This works, but doesn't fully solve the issue, check my edit of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `__new__` method to handle this.  You don't want to call `__init__` unless you want to create a new object with a new key, and `__new__` can be used to first check if the key is unique before calling `__init__`.

```
class Master(object):

    instances = {}
    def __new__(cls, key, value=None):
        if key in Master.instances:
            return Master.instances[key]
        else:
            instance = super(Master, cls).__new__(cls)
            Master.instances[key] = instance
            return instance

    def __init__(self, key, value=None):
        self.value = value
```

Then you can create the objects with

```
>>> A = Master('A',0)
>>> B = Master('B',0)
>>> C = Master('A',1)
```

Since `A` and `C` have the same key, they will point to the same object and will effectively be the same instance.  Since `C` has the same key as `A`, it updates its value.

```
>>> print(A.value)
1
```

Any new changes to `A` will be seen in `C`, and vice versa.

```
>>> A.value = 5
>>> print(C.value)
5
```

But changes to `A` and `C` will not affect `B`, and changes to `B` will not affect `A` or `C`.

**Edit:**

If you want to copy values but not instances, you could just store the values in the `Master.instances` dictionary and check if there's already values for the key.

```
class Master(object):

    instances = {}
    def __init__(self, key, value=None):
        if key in Master.instances:
            self.value = Master.instances[key]
        else:
            self.value = value
            Master.instances[key] = value

>>> A = Master('A',0)
>>> C = Master('A',1)
>>> print(C.value)
0
```

Comment: I tried something like this with the new method, but the interface for the object would involve the use of `new` keyword, and that doesn't feel that pythonic, but It does work, It feels more OO, but I'm not sure, I really want it to be as if you where instantiating a regular python object.

Comment: I see, if you just want to copy values, you can just store those values in the `Master.instances` dictionary.  Edited answer.